# Upload Picture in a particular folder of localhost

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

Hi I'm trying to take make a picture upload feature.In this the user selects a picture file in a form.I'm trying to validate whether the file uploaded is a picture or not.If yes then the picture should be saved in a folder named picture in the same parent folder as the html and php file. I'm trying but the picture is not getting validated or saved.Please help..

MY HTML file upload.html

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

MY PHP file  upload.php

```
     <?php
     $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
     $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     $extension = end($temp);

     if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
     || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
     && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
     && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     } else {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
     if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
     echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
     } else {
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
     "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     }
     }
     } else {
     echo "Invalid file";
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: check with your destination folder. you can try with '/upload/'

Comment: Script is working. Please check your file names! action="upload_file.php", and your php file should be named accordingly: upload_file.php. Also, currently - your upload size limit is 20kb. And, you should have 'upload' folder inside test folder on your localhost (test folder - folder where your html and php files are in)

Comment: and also check folder having writing permission or not

Comment: p.s. if you want to change folder name for file uploads - make folder called 'picture' and change it in code - 'picture' instead 'upload'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to change your form action to upload.php
Because You saved the php file with the name upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

if($_FILES['image']['name'])

```
    {
    $target='images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $source=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    copy($source,$target);
    }
```

Comment: images is folder name